# multiple parameters in a automated function(self made)

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering is there a simpler way to write this:

Any idea to set parameter b & c automatically ?
Or some else useful to make easier the write of function in makeInstruction(..

It's for my JS framework, some functions will be created and stored in lists(Array) in a Map and can be enabled/disabled or set in the requestAnimationFrame loop but that's no the subject here.

```js
function isReal(v) {
  return v !== null && !== undefined ? true : false
}
//-- there my functions
function makeInstruction(name, instr, args = null) {
  if (isString(name) && instr instanceof Function) {
    return args === null ? [name, instr] : [name, instr, toArray(args)]
  }
}

function readInstruction(instr) {
  let tx = 'FUNCTION readInstructions:\n';
  if (isArray(instr)) {
    if (isString(instr[0])) {
      if (instr[1] instanceof Function && instr.length < 4) {
        let res, ln = instr.length;
        saylog(instr.length);
        switch (ln) {
          case 3: //-- function instr[1] has argument(s)
            res = instr[1](instr[2]);
            tx += "NAME" + instr[0] + (isReal(res) ? ' result: ' + res : '');
            break;
          case 2: //-- function instr[1] has no argument
            res = instr[1]();
            tx += 'NAME' + instr[0] + (isReal(res) ? ' result: ' + res : '');
            break;
          default:
            tx += 'ERROR default length ' + ln;
            break;
        } //console.log(tx);
        return res;
      }
    }
  }
  return;
}
//-- there using functions
let ins = makeInstruction('someFunction', function() {
  return new Date.toLocaleString();
})
//-- no problem when no parameter:
console.log(readInstruction(ins))

let ins1Arg = makeInstruction('FN1arg', function(a) {
  return 'hello ' + a
}, 'world')
//-- ok Array converted to string:
console.log(redInstruction(ins1Arg)) //-- hello world [String]

let ins1ArgInt = makeInstruction('FN1argInt', function(a) {
  return 10 + parseInt(a)
}, 5)
//-- some trick using parseInt here but that do the job
let ins1console.log(readInstruction(ins1ArgInt)) //-- 15 [Number]

/** this work but boring to write
*let withArgs=makeInstruction('someFunc', function(a){ return (a[0]+a[1])*a[2]}, [1,2,10] )
console.log( readInstruction( withArgs ) )//-- 30
*/
/** i have tried this but it don't work
let withArgs=makeInstruction('someFunc', function(a,b,c){ arguments=a; return (a+b)*c}, [1,2,10] )
console.log( readInstruction( withArgs ) )//-- NaN
*/
//-- finally this but it's not quicker than the first i wrote
let withArgs = makeInstruction('someFunc', function(a) {
  arguments = a;
  return (arguments[0] + arguments[1]) * arguments[2]
}, [1, 2, 10])
console.log(readInstruction(withArgs)) //-- 30
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it to be a [mcve]. It may be that this question is for codereview instead of here

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Function.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [Function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
which allow you to execute a function and provide different ways of passing arguments.

```js
function Product(name, price) {
  return {
    name: name,
    price: price
  };
}

const args = ['My Name', 'My price']
console.log(Product(...args).name);
```

Comment: thanks for answering, i'm not familiar using Function.call & Function.apply() but just looked at .call and it don't solve my problem. I'll try the way you put it.

Comment: thank again Emile, fixed to that    case 3://-- function instr[1] has argument(s)
      res=instr[1](...instr[2]);
      tx+="NAME"+instr[0]+(isReal(res)?' result: '+res:'');
     break; console.log( readInstruction( makeInstruction('someFunction' , function(a,b,c){return (a+b)*c},[1,2,10]) ) )//--output: 30